# What is the best way to get the action name with Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm pretty new to Zend digging the docs but i can't find a good way to get the parameter i passed to my action...

Here is my uri :

```
/entreprise/name/foo
```

I would like to extract the name, `foo`. I'm actually able to get the action name with

```
$this->getRequest()->getActionName();
```

or the URI with

```
$this->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
```

With these two data i can parse the second string and get the name of my entreprise, but i quite surprised there is no best way to do this...

Is there a best to way to it ?

Comment: Are you using ZF1 or ZF2?

Comment: i use Zend framework 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the action name with:

```
$this->getRequest()->getActionName();
```

And additional data passed to this action by GET with:

```
$name = $this->_getParam('name', NULL);
```

This will get the GET-Value `name` if passed by URI, if not `$name` is set to null.

---

**Edit:**

As mentioned in the comments the way to pass vars is a bit different. Change it to

```
/entreprise/name/var/foo
```

And you'll be able to access `foo` this way:

```
$var = $this->_getParam('var', NULL);
```

Comment: how does your routing look like?
usually it looks like this:
`<controller>/<action>/<addParamName1>/<addParamValue1>`

So if `entreprise` is your called action, the code above should return the value `foo` for `name`.

Comment: nop `entreprise` is my controller, my action is `name` and foo the parameter

Comment: then you have to change the way you pass the parameter via uri. See my edit

Comment: Hum, weird. So i should pass my name this way `entreprise?name=toto` no? There is no need to add a dedicated action for this ?

Comment: you can add as much params by default via uri, as you want. usage is, as mentioned:
`<controller>/<action>/<addParamName1>/<addParamValue1/<addParamName2>/<addParamValue2>`

e.g:
`/entreprise/name/var/foo/var2/foo2`

No need for ugly `?var=value`

Answer (score 0):

In the following URI : `/entreprise/name/foo` if `entreprise` is your controller and `name` is your action, then the additional parameter will be used to call your action so you can get it by doing the following:

```
public function nameAction( $name = null )
{
    // $name == "foo"
}
```

Comment: `public function nameAction( $name = null ){ print_r($name);}` returns nothing...